# CDN set up with sub(folder) WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress, cdn

If I have my WordPress site, www.mysite.com

and I also have sub WP installation under this path.

```
www.mysite.com/siteA
www.mysite.com/siteB
www.mysite.com/siteC
```

each of these is independent WP installation.

If I want to set up CDN(via caching plugin), is it enough to set up on the root only(www.mysite.com) or I have to do it on each of subsite too(siteA, siteB, siteC, so 4 sites in total that I have to set up the CDN.)

Thank you!

Comment: you have to do it on each subsite bcoz you are using seprate installation of wordpress

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!